# What metrics work well in unbalanced assemblies?

Tags: model-evaluations, metric

I wanted to know if there are some metrics that work well when working with an unbalanced dataset. I know that accuracy is a very bad metric when evaluating a classifier when the data is unbalanced but, what about for example the Kappa index?

Best regards and thanks.

Comment: [Cross-posted on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/574303/what-metrics-work-well-in-unbalanced-assemblies) // [I would argue that class imbalance is minimally problematic.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he) // Check out Frank Harrell's two blog posts related to the idea of evaluating probability predictions: [(1)](https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/) [(2)](https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer I gave on the stats SE

> The choice of metric depends on the needs of the application, not the
> problems with the methods/tools.
>
> Accuracy is not a *very* bad metric; the main problem is that
> practitioners fail to use the relative class frequencies to calibrate
> their expectations.  If 95% of the data belong to the majority class
> and you get 94% accuracy then of course that isn't very impressive.
> One way to get around this is to look at accuracy gain, something like
>
> $$\frac{Accuracy - \pi}{1 - \pi}$$
>
> where $\pi$ is the relative frequency of the majority class.  If you
> achieve perfect performance you get a score of 1 - if you do as well
> as the majority classifier you get a score of 0 (indicating that your
> model has probably learned nothing of interest by looking at the
> attributes).  In the example above, you would get a negative score,
> indicating that the classifier is useless.   Now this is an affine
> transformation of accuracy, so it is **still** measuring exactly the
> same thing, just on a more interpretable scale.
>
> Imbalanced problems often have unequal misclassification costs, with
> false-negatives usually being more costly than false-positives, in
> which case you should probably look at the expected loss of the
> classifier instead of the accuracy.  Again, this means focussing on
> the needs of the application rather than the methods.
>
> However, for this sort of problem you should use a probabilistic
> classifier, such as [kernel] logistic regression, so you should look
> at metrics that measure the quality of the predictions of probability,
> such as the cross-entropy or Brier score.  Probabilistic classifiers
> are likely to be better as you can experiment with misclassification
> costs without refitting the model (and do things like implement a
> rejection operator).  When you have done that as a baseline, *then*
> perhaps experiment with non-probabilistic classifiers to see if they
> have benefits.